# How to generate 30 distinct colors that are color-blind friendly?

Tags: r, colors, web-deployment, color-blindness

I know some **R** packages like `randomcolorR` and `pals` can generate multiple distinct colors, but I do not know if they are color blind friendly?

Is there a better way to get ~30 distinct colors that are also color-blind friendly? Or is there any table/web I can search for colors that are color-blind friendly? So that I can pick manually.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that all colors are colorblind friendly; the consideration is whether sets of colors can be distinguished by colorblind viewers. I would find out what the rules are for those relations — something like avoiding color pairs whose only difference lies in red or green — and do the work in a perceptual colorspace such as YCbCr instead of RGB.

Comment: Maybe of any help https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/#%23D81B60-%231E88E5-%23FFC107-%23004D40

Comment: The package RColorBrewer  has color-blind friendly palettes.

Comment: There are 8 colors [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/#a-colorblind-friendly-palette) (but obviously that's insufficient, but at least a start)

Comment: 30 distinct colors is a lot, even for people with "normal" color vision.  Most of the designed color-blind friendly palettes limit the number of colors in a set to still consider it color-blind friendly.

Comment: Adjacent to your question: To check how a data viz would appear to a colorblind person, you can use simulators such as https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/

Comment: @Lamia that's extrmely interesting. Are all 8 of the views corresponding to different variants of colorblindness? (e.g. Red-Weak/Protanomaly, etc etc) ?

Comment: @stevec Yes, they are all different kinds of color blindness. The most common one is Green-Weak/Deuteranomaly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that [some sources recommend not using more than 8 colors in a colorblind-friendly palette](https://thenode.biologists.com/data-visualization-with-flying-colors/research/)

> Also, it is recommended to use no more than 8 different colors.

In any case:

[Here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/#a-colorblind-friendly-palette) are 2 (similar) palettes of 8 colorblind friendly colors

[image]

```r
# The palette with grey:
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

# The palette with black:
cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
```

And [here](https://jacksonlab.agronomy.wisc.edu/2016/05/23/15-level-colorblind-friendly-palette)'s a palette of 15 colorblind-friendly colors

[image]

```r
pal <- c("#000000","#004949","#009292","#ff6db6","#ffb6db",
 "#490092","#006ddb","#b66dff","#6db6ff","#b6dbff",
 "#920000","#924900","#db6d00","#24ff24","#ffff6d")
```

Comment: I think 30 is too many. I will choose your answer, since your colors seem most distinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

The [viridis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html) package is one option, e.g. `viridis::viridis(30)` will do it.

Comment: I believe this is not categorical color?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `RColorBrewer` to do that. It seems it has 27 colors for colorblind

```
library(RColorBrewer)
n <- 30
colrs <- brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$colorblind == TRUE, ]
col_vec = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, colrs$maxcolors, rownames(colrs)))
col <- sample(col_vec, n)
area <- rep(1,n)
pie(area, col = col)
```

[image]

colors:

```
[1] "#E5F5F9" "#1D91C0" "#67001F" "#F7FCFD" "#CB181D" "#78C679" "#F46D43" "#A6CEE3" "#FD8D3C" "#A6D854"
    [11] "#D4B9DA" "#6A51A3" "#7F0000" "#D9D9D9" "#FFF7BC" "#000000" "#F0F0F0" "#C7EAE5" "#003C30" "#F16913"
    [21] "#FFF7FB" "#8C6BB1" "#C7E9B4" "#762A83" "#FC9272" "#AE017E" "#F7F7F7" "#DF65B0" "#EF3B2C" "#74C476"
```

Comment: This is clever but wrong (I think).You can't get a bigger "colorblind-friendly" palette by squashing together two colorblind-friendly palettes!

Comment: @BenBolker Maybe you are right. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: #8 #12 and #26 are identical to me (colorblind)
1, 4, and 6 are very close too
same for 3, 18 19. 
I stop here as this will be different for other people suffering of color-blindness.
I also do not believe more than 8 colors can be used in that context. @stevec 's second set is fine although do not ask me to name these colors. 
This being another concept that non-color-blind have difficulties understanding. We often see the colors but cannot -name- them.
Hope this shed some light!